# omp doens't launch thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

openMp used to work on my project on 6 threads and now, (I have no ideas why), the program is single threaded. 
My code is pretty simple, I only use openMp in one cpp file, i declared
 `#include <omp.h>`

then the function to parallelize is :

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) num_threads(IntervalMapEstimator::m_num_thread)
for (int cell_index_x = m_min_cell_index_sensor_rot_x; cell_index_x <= m_max_cell_index_sensor_rot_x; cell_index_x++)
{
    for (int cell_index_y = m_min_cell_index_sensor_rot_y; cell_index_y <= m_max_cell_index_sensor_rot_y; cell_index_y++)
    {
        //use for debug
        omp_set_num_threads (5);
        std::cout << "omp_get_num_threads  = " <<  omp_get_num_threads ()<< std::endl;
        std::cout << "omp_get_max_threads = " << omp_get_max_threads ()<< std::endl;

        if(split_points) {
            extract_relevant_points_from_angle_lists(relevant_points, pointcloud_ff_polar_angle_lists, cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, cell_max_angle_sensor_rot);
        } else {
            extract_relevant_points_multithread_with_localvector(relevant_points, pointcloud, cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, cell_max_angle_sensor_rot);
        }
    }
}
```

`omp_get_num_threads` return 1 thread 
`omp_get_max_threads` return 5
`IntervalMapEstimator::m_num_thread` is set at 6

Any lead would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:
I modified my code but the problem remains, the program is still running in mono thread.
`omp_get_num_threads` return 1
`omp_get_max_threads` return 8

Is there a way to know how many threads are available at running time ?

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) 
    for (int cell_index_x = m_min_cell_index_sensor_rot_x; cell_index_x <= m_max_cell_index_sensor_rot_x; cell_index_x++)
    {
        for (int cell_index_y = m_min_cell_index_sensor_rot_y; cell_index_y <= m_max_cell_index_sensor_rot_y; cell_index_y++)
        {

            std::cout << "omp_get_num_threads  = " <<  omp_get_num_threads ()<< std::endl;
            std::cout << "omp_get_max_threads = " << omp_get_max_threads ()<< std::endl;


                extract_relevant_points(relevant_points, pointcloud, cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, cell_max_angle_sensor_rot);
            }
    }
```

I just saw my computer is beginning to run low in memory, could that be a part of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx15e8hb.aspx:

> If a parallel region is encountered while dynamic adjustment of the number of threads is disabled, and the number of threads requested for the parallel region exceeds the number that the run-time system can supply, the behavior of the program is implementation-defined. An implementation may, for example, interrupt the execution of the program, or it may serialize the parallel region.

You request 6 threads, the implementation can only provide 5, so it is free to do what it wants.

I'm also pretty sure you are not supposed to change the number of threads while inside a parallel region, so your `omp_set_num_threads` will do nothing at best and blow up in your face at worst.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question accordingly to your answer. I now let openMp decide on his own how many threads he should run, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the answer thanks to another post: [Why does the compiler ignore OpenMP pragmas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793363/why-does-the-compiler-ignore-openmp-pragmas][1])

In the end it was a simple error of library that i didn't add to the compiler, and I didn't noticed it because i was compiling with cmake so i don't have to type the line directly. Also i use catkin_make to compile so i don't have warning but only error in the console.

So basically, to use openMp you have to add -fopenmp as arguments to your compiler, and if you don't' ... well the lines are just ignored by the compiler.